# how to I add a scrollbar for the table

Tags: css, reactjs

i am mapping values on the table, i want the table to have scrollbar when it reaches some max-height,
adding overflow: scrollbar, width max-height: 600px did not work, the table just keeps extending downwards

```
    return (
        <div className='journaltable-div'>
        <table className='table table-journal'>
            <thead className='table-head'>
                <tr className='table-head-row'>
                    <th>Task</th>
                    <th>Date-created</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody className='table-body'>
                { journalList.map((entry) => {
                    const { key, journal, time } = entry
                    return (
                        <tr key={key} className="table-body-row">
                            <td>{journal}</td>
                            <td>{time}</td>
                            <td><button 
                                className='button button-complete'
                            onClick={(e) => {
                                e.stopPropagation
                                addToLog(key, "completed")
                                removeJournal(key)
                            }}>completed</button><button 
                                className='button button-delete'
                            onClick={(e) => {
                                e.stopPropagation
                                addToLog(key, "deleted")
                                removeJournal(key)
                            }}>delete</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    )
                }) }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div className='redirect-div'>
            <button  className='redirect-logs'  style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} onClick={() => {handleLogs()}}> Check Logs</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
.table-journal {
  overflow: scroll;
  max-height: 600px;
}
```

also tried placing on tbody did not work either

Answer (score 0):

put all of your return values from the map function in a div with scrollit style class and add these codes to your CSS:

```css
.scrollit {
    overflow:scroll;
    height:100px;
}
```

your code have look like this:

```js
return (
    <div className='journaltable-div'>
    <table className='table table-journal'>
        <thead className='table-head'>
            <tr className='table-head-row'>
                <th>Task</th>
                <th>Date-created</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody className='table-body'>
         <div className="scrollit">
           { journalList.map((entry) => {
                const { key, journal, time } = entry
                return (
                    <tr key={key} className="table-body-row">
                        <td>{journal}</td>
                        <td>{time}</td>
                        <td><button 
                            className='button button-complete'
                        onClick={(e) => {
                            e.stopPropagation
                            addToLog(key, "completed")
                            removeJournal(key)
                        }}>completed</button><button 
                            className='button button-delete'
                        onClick={(e) => {
                            e.stopPropagation
                            addToLog(key, "deleted")
                            removeJournal(key)
                        }}>delete</button></td>
                    </tr>
                )
            }) }
         </div>     
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div className='redirect-div'>
        <button  className='redirect-logs'  style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} onClick={() => {handleLogs()}}> Check Logs</button>
    </div>
</div>
```